# How to modify my VLOOKUP() to search for only 1 character?

Tags: excel, excel-2007, excel-formula, formula, vba

I have several cells in an Excel Workbook with dropdown lists. Other cells use VLOOKUP() to search reference worksheets for the description of the dropdown value code.

I had to modify my dropdown lists to contain not only the value code, but also the description. Because of this, my VLOOKUP() for the other cells no longer function correctly, searching for the whole value,such as "**1 - Bag**", instead of "**1**".

**Dropdown List Example - Cell(F5)**
Before: 1, 2, 3, 4, 5
After:  1 - Bag, 2- Liquid, 3 - Solid, 4 - Can, etc.

**Reference Cell Example - Cell(A21)**
Before: =IFERROR(VLOOKUP(F5,SampleFrom!1:10,2,FALSE),"")
After:

Can someone assist me with modifying my formula to search for only the first character of the cell value, in this example above the first character of F5's value? I'm still horribly amateur when it comes to Microsoft Excel.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

either

```
=IFERROR(VLOOKUP(LEFT(F5,1),SampleFrom!1:10,2,FALSE),"")
```

or if the lookup value should be a true number

```
=IFERROR(VLOOKUP(--left(F5,1),SampleFrom!1:10,2,FALSE),"")
```

Comment: Sadly the following does not appear to be working. Returning only a blank value :/
`=IFERROR(VLOOKUP(LEFT(F5,1),SampleFrom!1:10,2,FALSE),"")`

Comment: did you try the alternate version?

Comment: @JosieP looks like the alternate version works when I test this. The first version fails because the `Left` function returns a string, and the lookup table likely contains numeric values. Your second version converts to numeric and seems to be working correctly.

Comment: JosieP It looks as if I performed the age old mistake of making an @$$ of myself and just assumed the second would not work when the first didn't... looks like number 2 does the trick! Thanks!

@David Thanks for explaining the reasoning behind the first solution failing and the second working.